# Add margin to the "Communities" block on the profile activity page

Tags: feature-request, support, design, profile-page

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community

> [image]

Actually, `h` tags have `margin`:

```
h1, h2, h3 {
    margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

But "Communities" block has class `.gs4`, which overides this rule:

```
.gs4 {
    margin: -2px;
}
```

Could you fix it?